# Синхронный цикл

Tags: javascript, async-await

У меня есть массив объектов. Для каждого объекта мне нужно вызвать асинхронную функцию, дождаться ее выполнения, а потом перейти к следующей итерации.

Делаю по мотивам [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/554337/221228) ответа через async/await

```js
async function process(data) {
  .........
  await asyncFunc({
    data: data,
    onfinished: function() {
      console.log("Finished");
    }
  });
}

async function loop() {
  const data = [1, 2, 3];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    ......
    console.log(data[i])
    await process(data[i]);
  }
}
```

И вижу в консоли

```
1
2
3
Finished
Finished
Finished
```

Чего не хватает для счастья?

Функция `asyncFunc` посылает аякс-запрос. Но она моя и изменить ее я не могу

Comment: Нормальная асинхронная функция, работающая с промисами не должна принимать коллбек onfinished как параметр. Надо смотреть ее исходники. Либо создавать свой промис и делать его выполненным уже внутри onfinished

Comment: @Mike Это не нормальная асинхронная функция, работающая с промисами. И принимает она именно коллбек

Comment: Тогда вам нужно писать обёртку вокруг этой функции с разрешением промиса изнутри колбека.

Comment: @Mike ну вызову я внутри `onfinished` `resolve`. Я не соображу как мне по массиву пройтись синхронно, даже если `process` вернет промис

Comment: @vsemozhebuty Так `.then()` тоже ведь вернет промис. Как мне его вызов организовать для цикла?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так?

```js
function process(data) {
  // .........
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    asyncFunc({
      data: data,
      onfinished: resolve,
    });
  });
}

async function loop() {
  const data = [1, 2, 3];
  for (const item of data) {
    // ......
    console.log(item)
    await process(item);
    console.log("Finished");
  }
}
```

Comment: Да. Спасибо большое